# How to solve EOFError SSH in test execution

Tags: robotframework

The robot logfile shows following:

> INFO  Executing command '/testcase_xy.py'.     DEBUG  [chan 28] Max
>   packet in: 32768 bytes     INFO   Command exited with return code 0.
>
> INFO: Executing command '/testcase_xy_next.py'. DEBUG     [chan 43] Max
>   packet in: 32768 bytes FAIL   EOFError DEBUG  Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line
>   881, in execute_command
>       stdout, stderr, rc = self.current.execute_command(command)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/abstractclient.py",
>   line 219, in execute_command
>       self.start_command(command)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/abstractclient.py",
>   line 237, in start_command
>       self._started_commands.append(self._start_command(command))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py",
>   line 85, in _start_command
>       cmd.run_in(new_shell)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/abstractclient.py",
>   line 1055, in run_in
>       self._execute()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py",
>   line 201, in _execute
>       self._shell.exec_command(self._command)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 60,
>   in _check
>       return func(self, *args, **kwds)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 229,
>   in exec_command
>       self._wait_for_event()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line
>   1086, in _wait_for_event
>       raise e

I have seen these behaviour in several different steps during the test execution.

Can someone help me whats the problem is or how we can solve it?

Comment: Probably it's going to be a good idea to provide the content of the executed file /testcase_xy_next.py

Comment: Its a simple case:  The testcase gives me a directory from the test vehicle:                                                                                                #!/usr/bin/python -u

import os
import sys
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

print "-> my script called"

cmd = 'ls -axl'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()

print "OUTPUT IS:"
print ""
print output
exit (0)

Comment: If you run the python file in a SSH terminal session, does it work?